# Escaping a SELECT statement for storing a in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a need to store a select statement in a column.

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TAB(THE_KEY, THE_SELECT)
VALUES (1, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ANOTHER_TAB')
```

When the selects are simple, then it is easy, but when the selects get more complex, then it gets to be a pain to maintain the proper escaping of the select and the formatting.

For instance, it is easier to read a SELECT if it looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM ANOTHER_TAB
```

But that requires me to put in line breaks within the quoted text.

For another issue, it is a pain to escape the quotes like this 'STATUS = ''ON'''.
I would like to just code one quote.

Yet another issue is that I lose syntax highlighting as soon as I put the select in quotes.

Is there some kind of stored procedure some thing else that will help with the formatting?

I am thinking it could look like this:

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TAB(THE_KEY, THE_SELECT)
VALUES (1, 
QUOTETHIS(SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM ANOTHER_TAB 
           WHERE STATUS = 'ON'
         ))
```

That is, QUOTETHIS takes everything between the parens and quotes it.  This is much like the `qw()` feature of Perl.

Another idea is to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO SOME_TAB(THE_KEY, THE_SELECT)
VALUES (1, READFILEASSTRING('FILE_CONTAINS_SELECT.sql'))
```

Then I could maintain a bunch of individual files that contain the selects and then syntax highlighting would work.

Comment: If you use a parameterized query for the insert then it shouldn't be an issue. Are you using an application to insert rows or just fiddling about in SSMS? If the latter, just tell it to edit rows in the table (right-click on the table in the explorer) and enter the queries.

Comment: Why don't use just use management studio and paste the text in.

Comment: @Vincent I don't use management studio for this problem because it is an automated script.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be ideal, but why not use of a different character for the escape character (') such as: | and then all you need to do is use the REPLACE method to replace the | character with the escape character.

[Click here for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X1ql.png)